A plane or surface passing through two surfaces in MATLAB
I have just been able to plot several surfaces using the code below. What I want is a plane or a surface that connects the black and yellow region in the output of the code below:
% Define parameters
omega = 1;
p = 0.5;
% Define ranges for y, z
y_range = linspace(0, 1, 100); % Adjust the range based 
on the expected range of y values
z_range1 = linspace(0, 0.25, 100);  % Range for the first 
plot
z_range2 = linspace(0.25, 0.75, 100);  % Range for the 
second plot
z_range3 = linspace(0.75, 1, 100);  % Range for the third 
plot
% Create a grid of y and z values for each plot
[y1, z1] = meshgrid(y_range, z_range1);
[y2, z2] = meshgrid(y_range, z_range2);
[y3, z3] = meshgrid(y_range, z_range3);
% Define the lower and upper limit functions for each 
plot
x_lower1 = (1 + (z1 / 0.25)) * (y1 .^ (p - 1)) .* mlf(p, 
p, omega .* (y1 .^ (p)), 10);  % Lower limit function for 
the first plot
x_upper1 = (6 - (z1 / 0.75)) * (y1 .^ (p - 1)) .* mlf(p, 
p, omega .* (y1 .^ (p)), 10);  % Upper limit function for 
the first plot
x_lower2 = (2 + ((z2 - 0.25) / 0.75)) * (y2 .^ (p - 1)) 
.* mlf(p, p, omega .* (y2 .^ (p)), 10);  % Lower limit 
function for the second plot
x_upper2 = (6 - (z2 / 0.75)) * (y2 .^ (p - 1)) .* mlf(p, 
p, omega .* (y2 .^ (p)), 10);  % Upper limit function for 
the second plot
x_lower3 = (2 + ((z3 - 0.25) / 0.75)) * (y3 .^ (p - 1)) 
.* mlf(p, p, omega .* (y3 .^ (p)), 10);  % Lower limit 
function for the third plot
x_upper3 = (5 - ((z3 - 0.75) / 0.25)) * (y3 .^ (p - 1)) 
.* mlf(p, p, omega .* (y3 .^ (p)), 10);  % Upper limit 
function for the third plot
% Define the additional surfaces f_1 and f_2
%f_1 = x_lower1;
%f_2 = x_lower2;
% Define coefficients for the general surface
a = 1; % Example coefficient for f_1
b = 1; % Example coefficient for f_2
% Define the general surface
%general_surface = f_1 - f_2;
hold on 
% Plot for the first range
surf(y1, z1, x_lower1, 'FaceColor', 'b', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');  % Plot lower limit function for the first plot
surf(y1, z1, x_upper1, 'FaceColor', 'r', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');  % Plot upper limit function for the first plot
% Plot for the second range
surf(y2, z2, x_lower2, 'FaceColor', 'y', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');  % Plot lower limit function for the second plot
surf(y2, z2, x_upper2, 'FaceColor', 'r', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');  % Plot upper limit function for the second plot
% Plot for the third range
surf(y3, z3, x_lower3, 'FaceColor', 'y', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');  % Plot lower limit function for the third plot
surf(y3, z3, x_upper3, 'FaceColor', 'k', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');  % Plot upper limit function for the third plot
% Plot the general surface
surf(y3, z3, x_lower1, 'FaceColor', 'c', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');
%surf(y3, z3, x_lower2, 'FaceColor', 'c', 'EdgeColor', 
'none');
% Plot general surface
xlabel('y');
ylabel('z');
zlabel('x');
title('Combined Plot of x as a function of y and z');
% Add a legend
legend('Lower Limit (Range 1)', 'Upper Limit (Range 1)', 
'Lower Limit (Range 2)', 'Upper Limit (Range 2)', 'Lower 
Limit (Range 3)', 'Upper Limit (Range 3)');
hold off

The output 3D figure observed was:

I tried to produce what I desired using the general surface equation f1-f2 by defining f1=x_lower1 and f2=x_lower2; but the output was not what I expected. Any hints on how I should proceed?
Thanks beforehand.

I have no idea what it is you are hoping to do. What is "a plane or a surface that connects the black and yellow region"? How do you define mathematically what you are looking for? You can't implement something you don't define clearly.

Basically, it is just some surface that connects the regions defined by x_loeer1 and x_lower2

"some surface" is not a concise definition. You won't get answers if you can't define what it is you want.

@WolfgangBangerth ok. Suppose say I want a plane that connects x_lower1 and x_lower2? Is it now well defined?

No, not really. Are x_lower1 and x_lower2 lines? Curves? Surfaces? If they are arbitrary lines, no plane will in general intersect them. If they are surfaces, more or less any plane will intersect them. For example, the plane $z=0.5$ "connects" the yellow and red surfaces in your plot. I still do not really know what "connect" means, what kinds of objects you want to connect, and if there are multiple ways of connecting them how you want to choose them.

@WolfgangBangerth Thanks. By the way, how did you guess that $z=0.5$ connects the yellow and black regions? Like, is there any importance for $0.5$. When can I say that a plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ connects the two regions?

@WolfgangBangerth By the way, will x_lower4=0.5 and plot3d(y1,z1,x_lower4, 'FaceColor','g','EdgeColor','none'); produce thw desired connecting plane? I tried, but the picture did not change.

Just looking at the figure you show, I can see that a vertical plane intersects both the yellow and black surfaces. There is no magic to it. As for the other part: I get the impression that you do not really understand what your picture actually shows, what the plot3d command should produce, and why it doesn't. That's a problem we can't help you with. You have to be able to precisely define what it is you want; we can't help you with that.
